# How to add several arrows without writing them one by one with matplotlib and mendeleev?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In my graph I have a curve giving the electronegativity according to the atomic number. I would like that from each value given by the mendeleev library starts an arrow giving precisely the value of the electronegativity.
I would like not to write the arrows one by one but to do it automatically.

```py
from mendeleev import element
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
x, y = range(1,108), [element(i).en_pauling for i in range(1,108)]
for i in range(1,108):
    print(x[i-1], y[i-1])
  
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xticks([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 108])
plt.yticks([0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5])
plt.xlim(0,108)
plt.ylim(0,5)
plt.grid()
plt.savefig("En_pauling.png")

plt.xlabel("Le numéro atomique Z")  
plt.ylabel("Electronégativité selon Pauling")
plt.title("Evolution de l'électronégativité selon Pauling des 108 premiers éléments")
plt.plot(x,y,color='purple', marker = '+')
plt.plot(x, y, 'c')
plt.annotate('Carbone EN=2.6', xy=(6, 2.55), xytext=(25, 4.25), 
arrowprops={'facecolor':'black', 'shrink':0.05} )
plt.annotate('Fer EN=1.83', xy=(26, 1.83), xytext=(30, 3.25), 
arrowprops={'facecolor':'black', 'shrink':0.05} )
plt.annotate('Or EN=2.6', xy=(79, 2.54), xytext=(80, 3.5), 
arrowprops={'facecolor':'black', 'shrink':0.05} )
plt.show()
```

[image: Annotating Pauling numbers]
I would like not to have to write them one by one but to do it automatically while using the mendeleev library.
If this is possible, can the arrow start perpendicular to my curve.

Comment: You could plot all the annotations automatically using some fixed arrow, and then try [the adjustText library](https://adjusttext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Examples.html) to move around overlappings.  From your question, it isn't clear whether you want all 108 elements or just some subset.  You also might want to specify a figsize in `plt.figure(figsize=...)`.

Comment: Yes, I would like to have 108 elements so 108 arrows. But I would like to do it automatically using mendeleev for the electronegativity values.

Comment: 108 names and arrow won't fit, even if you'd position them manually. Why do you think the result wouldn't be overcrowded? Anyway, if you really want to, you can place all text at fixed offsets, and let the `adjustText` library move them around.  Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing the strategy and using something like [plotly](https://plotly.com/) or [bokeh](https://bokeh.org/) and display actual values when hovering over points. Some time ago I  made and app with bokeh with exactly that, if you're interested the relevant function is [here](https://github.com/lmmentel/mendeleevapp/blob/ecedd620c4a5fd79fe7a961f854e3b69067d6024/app/views.py#L297).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35856536)